# Does this esoteric representation of integers have decidable equality?

Tags: computability, functional-programming, semi-decidability, equality, topology

Consider the following datatypes in Haskell:

```
data Foo = Halt | Iter Foo
newtype BigInt = BigInt {nthBit :: Foo -> Bool}
```

`Foo` is Peano numbers compactified by one limit point, namely `fix Iter`. `BigInt` represents arbitrary-length integers in two's complement. The limit point `fix Iter` forces the field `nthBit` to eventually terminate in infinite string of zeros, or infinite string of ones.

Since `Foo` is compact and `Bool` is discrete, `BigInt` expresses a discrete function space. But does this mean `BigInt` has decidable equality?

Semideciding inequality of `BigInt` is easy. Given two different integers, Keep evaluating their `nthBit` fields at `Halt`, `Iter Halt`, `Iter (Iter Halt)` and so on until they mismatch.

But what about semideciding equality? Given two equal integers, mathematically their equality at `fix Iter` should already serve as a proof that they might mismatch only at finitely many bits, but that doesn't give the range of the might-be mismatch.

Or was it my misconception that discreteness implies decidable equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun question! Yes equality is *externally* decidable here, though I don't know if the procedure is *internally* expressible in Haskell. Here's a more direct solution:

Let `infty` be the infinite integer `fix Iter`. On input `a` and `b`:

- Run `a infty` and `b infty`. If they are unequal, return "false"
- Otherwise, track the number of steps that each of the above computations takes to run, and let $N$ be the maximum of the two. Then it follows that, since `a` and `b` cannot distinguish `infty` from an integer that is N or greater, the Nth digits and greater of both `a` and `b` must be equal to `a infty` and `b infty`. So it remains only to check the digits from 0 to N are equal; if they are all equal, return "true", else return "false".

---

The crux of the argument is that "`a` and `b` cannot distinguish `infty` from an integer that is N or greater". This should be true in Haskell, but it is also why I am not sure if this procedure is internally expressible. Functions cannot introspect on `infty` to see its implementation, so they cannot do anything on input `infty` other than run it some finite number of times or diverge.

But the procedure above fundamentally relies on running `a infty` and `b infty` to see how long they run. That is a bit weaker than inspecting the implementation of `a` and `b`, but it may not be possible in a purely functional way, or at least I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you intend to only count the total functions for $\mathsf{BigInt}$, then yes, equality should be decidable. Here's a sketch for how to do it for $i$ and $j$:

1. First test $i$ and $j$  on $\infty$. If they differ, then they are unequal. If they both yield $1$, then run the subsequent tests with $-i$ and $-j$ obtained by flipping the output of $i$ and $j$.
2. Due to continuity, we know that there are only finitely many $1$ indices remaining in $i$, so we can be sure that the following loop will complete:

   1. [Search](https://math.andrej.com/2007/09/28/seemingly-impossible-functional-programs/) for $\bar{n} : \mathsf{Foo}$ such that  $i\ \bar{n} = 1$. If you don't find one, the loop is complete. Otherwise check that $j\ \bar{n} = 1$. If not, then $i \neq j$. Otherwise ...
   2. Find $n : ℕ$ that corresponds to the above value. I believe this requires [Markov's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_principle) (unbounded search is okay as long as we know not all $n$ are $0$).
   3. Continue the loop with $i'$ and $j'$, which agree with $i$ and $j$, except that $i'\ \bar{n} = j'\ \bar{n} = 0$. This is accomplished by induction on $n$. In Haskell, you could just recurse on $\bar{n}$, but the reasoning that this is okay is analogous to Markov's principle ($\bar{n}$ is not $\infty$, so it is finite). Note of course that $i = j \leftrightarrow i' = j'$.
3. When this process finishes, you are left with $i = \mathsf{const}\ 0$. But now you can easily test for equality with the remaining $j$ by searching for $\bar{n} : \mathsf{Foo}$ such that $j\ \bar{n} = 1$. If you find one, $i \neq j$. Otherwise $i = j$.

[Here is](https://hub.darcs.net/dolio/unpossible/browse/src/Decide.agda#70) an Agda formalization of this approach. It might look lengthy, but quite a bit of that is due to proving things about how it behaves. Just writing down the more simply typed procedure in Haskell would be considerably shorter. Markov's principle and continuity are implemented as assertions about the termination of certain recursive functions that Agda's checker would otherwise reject.

Comment: "If you don't find one, the loop is complete." — How can the loop be exited when `Foo` has infinitely many elements?

Comment: Continuity of total functions $\mathsf{Foo} → \mathsf{Bool}$ entails that there are only finitely many values of $\mathsf{Foo}$ that are $1$ when $i\ \infty = 0$. Compactness of $\mathsf{Foo}$ allows exhaustive searching by a total boolean predicate in finite time (I added a reference that discusses this for the Cantor space; I thought it was implicit in your question). Together, this means we do a finite number of iterations of searches that take a finite amount of time.

Comment: You could also use continuity to say that there is a finite $\bar{n}$ such that $i\ \bar{n} = 1$ or $j\ \bar{n} = 1$, but $i\ \bar{m} = j\ \bar{m} = 0$ for all $\bar{m} > \bar{n}$. Then check $i\ \bar{m} = j\ \bar{m}$ for all $\bar{m} \leq \bar{n}$. But, the way(s) I know to find this $\bar{n}$ correspond(s) to procedures like the one in my answer.